# Can't upload an image to imgur with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, httpclient, imgur

I am working on project that I need to upload image to imgur.com, I wrote the code but it didn't work when came to posting part! any suggestions?

```
 private async Task<string> UploadImageAsync(string imageDataBase64String)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.imgur.com/3/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Client-id " + ClientID);
        HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(imageDataBase64String);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("image", contentPost);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(responseContent);
        var imageLink = model["data"]["link"];
        return imageLink;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work? Does the `PostAsync` call throw an exception? Does it appear to succeed but the image isn't showing on imgur?

Comment: There is no exceptions, just when the code reached to 'PostAsync' the page is waiting and it doesn't do any thing.. just waiting without any respond..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on similar project and here is how I did it.

- Create a view models for imgur response:

  ```
  public class ImgurResponseViewModel
  {
      public ImgurImageDataViewModel Data { get; set; }
      public bool Success { get; set; }
      public int Status { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Create a view models for image data:

  ```
  public class ImgurImageDataViewModel
  {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public string Datetime { get; set; }
      public string Type { get; set; }
      public bool Animated { get; set; }
      public int Width { get; set; }
      public int Height { get; set; }
      public int Size { get; set; }
      public int Views { get; set; }
      public int Bandwidth { get; set; }
      public string Ddeletehash { get; set; }
      public string Section { get; set; }
      public string Link { get; set; }
      public string Account_url { get; set; }
      public int Aaccount_id { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- And this is the code for uploading:

  ```
  private async Task<string> UploadImageAsync(string imageDataBase64String)
  {
      byte[] response;
      using (var client = new WebClient())
      {
          string clientID = "YourClientID";
          client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientID);
          var values = new NameValueCollection { { "image", imageDataBase64String } };
          response = await client.UploadValuesTaskAsync("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload", values);
      }

      var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImgurResponseViewModel>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response));

      return result.Data.Link;
  }
  ```

I hope this will help you.